# Using Case When with ON clause SQL - Netezza

Tags: sql, join, netezza, case-when

please I have the below Code

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CASE WHEN LENGTH (i.MOBILE_NUMBER) = 10 THEN 0||i.MOBILE_NUMBER ELSE i.MOBILE_NUMBER END AS New_Mob_Num,
COUNT(i.SUBS_ID) AS Subs_Count,
COUNT(s.MESSAGEID) AS SMS_COUNT,
              SUM(CASE WHEN s.MESSAGESTATE = 'Undeliverable' THEN COUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Undeliverablecount,
              SUM(CASE WHEN s.MESSAGESTATE = 'Delivered' THEN COUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Deliveredcount
    FROM PRD_STG.MOB.INF_SUBSCRIBER i
    INNER JOIN ANALYTICS.sms.mq s 
ON i.New_Mob_Num = strright(s.destination, 11)
GROUP BY 1
```

and I got an error `ERROR:  Attribute 'I.NEW_MOB_NUM' not found`

who can I use the column **CASE WHEN LENGTH (i.MOBILE_NUMBER) = 10 THEN 0||i.MOBILE_NUMBER ELSE i.MOBILE_NUMBER END AS New_Mob_Num** with ON clause while **Joining**.

and when using the CASE WHEN statement with ON clause like below, I got a wrong results

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CASE WHEN LENGTH (i.MOBILE_NUMBER) = 10 THEN 0||i.MOBILE_NUMBER ELSE i.MOBILE_NUMBER END AS New_Mob_Num,
COUNT(i.SUBS_ID) AS Subs_Count,
COUNT(s.MESSAGEID) AS SMS_COUNT,
              SUM(CASE WHEN s.MESSAGESTATE = 'Undeliverable' THEN COUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Undeliverablecount,
              SUM(CASE WHEN s.MESSAGESTATE = 'Delivered' THEN COUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Deliveredcount
    FROM PRD_STG.MOB.INF_SUBSCRIBER i
    INNER JOIN ANALYTICS.sms.mq s 
ON (CASE WHEN LENGTH (i.MOBILE_NUMBER) = 10 THEN 0||i.MOBILE_NUMBER ELSE i.MOBILE_NUMBER END) 
= strright(s.destination, 11)
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: You have to use a subquery to define the column alias.  SQL in general -- and Netezza in particular -- does not allow the use of a column alias defined in the `SELECT` in the `FROM` or `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: I tried to use a subquery like: ```ON (SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH (MOBILE_NUMBER) = 10 THEN 0||MOBILE_NUMBER ELSE MOBILE_NUMBER END
FROM PRD_STG.MOB.INF_SUBSCRIBER) = strright(s.destination, 11)
``` but I got another error : ```ERROR:  58192812 : More than one tuple returned by a subselect used as an expression```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I mean:

```
SELECT i.New_Mob_Num ,
       COUNT(i.SUBS_ID) AS Subs_Count,
       COUNT(s.MESSAGEID) AS SMS_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.MESSAGESTATE = 'Undeliverable' THEN COUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Undeliverablecount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.MESSAGESTATE = 'Delivered' THEN COUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Deliveredcount
FROM (SELECT i.*,
             (CASE WHEN LENGTH (i.MOBILE_NUMBER) = 10 
                   THEN '0'||i.MOBILE_NUMBER
                   ELSE i.MOBILE_NUMBER
              END) AS New_Mob_Num
      FROM PRD_STG.MOB.INF_SUBSCRIBER i
     ) i JOIN
     ANALYTICS.sms.mq s 
     ON i.New_Mob_Num = strright(s.destination, 11)
GROUP BY 1;
```

That should fix your syntax error.  If this doesn't do anything useful, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: thanks Gordon a lot for your kind support, it works like a charm